# Does Chrome App works with large data like POS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am planning to create a POS System using Chrome App and Indexed DB as the backend. I just want to know if it could cater/work with large data.

Let's say that this app will be used in a big restaurant that has a thousands of transactions per day and a thousand of Inventory list with image of each item.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Chrome App per se will be the problem. It's where you store your data that needs scaling. For that Google has [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/), built automatically for scaling.
Several businesses are already using Chrome Apps. Check this [list of Chrome apps](https://www.google.com/intl/en_ph/chrome/business/webstore/business-apps-gtd.html) being used for work. Who knows if your app will also be added to the list.